# how to save sass file in a different location?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

My gem file is saved in **c:\users\myname** so I can save scss file to css file as I enter command line :

```
  c:\users\myname> sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

But I would like to save scss file to a css file on desktop or in another file. What kind of command line do I have to use? I searched it but no results!

I have found something like that but as I enter that, I get "system cant find the path"

```
c:\users\myname>/Desktop/myfile/css/style.scss:style.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the answer: to change following path:

```
C:\Users\PcName\
```

add

```
C:\Users\PcName\ cd C:\Users\PcName\Desktop\anyfile
```

**enter** and the my new path:

```
C:\Users\PcName\Desktop\anyfile
```

and at last for this question:

```
C:\Users\PcName\Desktop\anyfile\ sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

`sass --watch input.scss:"c:\users\myname\Desktop\output.css"`

*Update the path to your actual path.*

The path on Windows nees to be between quotes most likely, since it contains a `:` already.